# How to iterate through d3 nested data

Tags: d3.js

I have a nested data array after using d3.nest on csv data as in this fiddle [nested data](https://jsfiddle.net/rkkamath/cbkts5em/). I want to write a reusable function that recursively loops through this kind of an array and makes groups for each key found and stops only when "key" is not found. For every level of groups I want to set a y domain.

```
let nestedData = [{
        key: "A",
        values: [{
            key: "ab",
            values: [{
                key: "xy",
                values: [{
                  name: "tom"
                }]
              },
              {
                key: "tu",
                values: [{
                  name: "corin"
                }]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            key: "cd",
            values: [{
              key: "xy",
              values: [{
                name: "nancy"
              }]
            }]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        key: "B",
        values: [{
            key: "ab",
            values: [{
              key: "xy",
              values: [{
                name: "tom"
              }]
            }]
          },
          {
            key: "cd",
            values: [{
              key: "xy",
              values: [{
                name: "nancy"
              }]
            }]
          }
        ]
      }]
```

Final aim is to draw a horizontal bar chart that has y axis groupings ( like the x axis grouping in this [nested x axis image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wR04w.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @RyanMorton tried rollup and passing to a recursive function to count number of leaves at each level and then use that to calculate height of each group. But using rollup removes the node properties that I need for labelling down the road. Check https://jsfiddle.net/rkkamath/acqtp1dw/

Comment: Recursion is the way to go

Comment: @Shan-Desai I realize that but being a newbie at d3, having problems recursively creating groups and setting y domains for each level.

Comment: Not a computer science guy here. But have a look at my [repo](https://github.com/shantanoo-desai/d3Ang/blob/master/src/app/treediag/model/recursion.ts), which is in typescript but I used it to parse my json for d3 application.

Here is my [json structure](https://github.com/shantanoo-desai/d3Ang/blob/master/src/app/fd-ontology/ontology.ts) for comparison

Answer (score 0):

Create a class called `node`:

```
export class Node {
  public id: number;
  public attr: any[] = [];
  public children: Node[] = [];
}
```

create a `recursion` class:

```
export class recursion {

  private nodes: any[] = [];


  public parse(ont: any): any {

    let linkedTree = this.parse_node(jsonInput);
    // console.log({'nodes': this.nodes});
    return {'nodes': this.nodes}

  }


  private parse_node(jsonVal: any): any {
    let node = new Node();
    node.id = this.nodes.length;
    this.nodes.push({
      name: jsonVal.key,
      id: this.nodes.length,
    });
    for (let value of jsonVal.values) {
      this.nodes.push({
        name: value.name,
        id: this.nodes.length,
      });
      node.attr.push(this.nodes.length);
  }
  for (let eachVal in jsonInput.values) {
    if (jsonInput.values.hasOwnProperty(eachVal)) {
      // recursion..
      node.children.push(
        this.parse_node(jsonVal['values'][eachVal])
      );
    }
  }
  return node;
  }
```

### Warning

1. This code is written is `typescript`
2. I am not a computer science guy and recursion is not my strong point but going ahead and suggesting this answer. Perhaps you can adapt the logic to your need.